# Parse dates for datetype as DDMMMYYYY

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strptime

Currently my data has date as `01JAN2017`, how do I make pandas understand this as date type, i need the data to be in date type for filtering it for various time frames.
i used the below

```
data=pd.read_csv(input_path + 'data.txt',sep='|', parse_dates=['week'])
```

but when i checked for the datatype for week it still shows as object.

Would be very helpful if you can also direct me to some other links so that i could read up more about this

Comment: Hint: `datetime.strptime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse a date string into a `datetime` object:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime("01JAN2017", "%d%b%Y")
>>> datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Now, to make pandas recognize the format, you could add a date parser function:

```
dateparse = lambda dates: [pd.datetime.strptime(d, "%d%b%Y") for d in dates]
df = pd.read_csv(infile, parse_dates=["week"], date_parser=dateparse)
```

Comment: will this increase my runtime as i would be using huge data with 3 date columns?

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas` `to_datetime` method is the natural choice

```
In [11]: D = {'Date': '01JAN2017'}
In [12]: df = pd.DataFrame(D, index=[0])
In [13]: df
Out[13]: 
        Date
0  01JAN2017
In [14]: df.dtypes
Out[14]: 
Date    object
dtype: object

# Datatime column is read as string
# use to_datetime to convert non-standard datetime values    

In [15]: df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%d%b%Y')
In [16]: df.dtypes
Out[16]: 
Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
In [17]: df['Date']
Out[17]: 
0   2017-01-01
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The document of `pd.read_csv` actually recommends that you use `to_datetime` when the datetime format is not a standard format:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html

> If a column or index contains an unparseable date, the entire column or index will be returned unaltered as an object data type. For non-standard datetime parsing, use pd.to_datetime after pd.read_csv